# javascript prevent from submit

Tags: javascript, webforms

Eu tenho uma caixa de texto e um botão . Eu só quero verificar o valor da caixa de texto com javascript e impedir de apresentar, se é nulo.

Aqui está aspx :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button CssClass="addButtonBlack" ID="ButtonAddDriver" OnClientClick="return IsNull();" OnClick="ButtonAddDriver_Click" runat="server" Text="Ekle" />
```

E o meu código javascript:

```
function IsNull() {
        var success = true;

        var name = document.getElementById('TextBoxName');
        if (name.value == "") {
            name.style.borderColor = '#e52213';
            name.style.border = 'solid';
            success = false;
        }
        if (success)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
```

A caixa texto é nulo. Como posso impedir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve ter algo como: `OnClientClick = "IsNull"`

```
function isNull(e) {
  if (it is null) e.preventDefault();
  else ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método javascript  **event.preventDefault()** para impedir que o evento default seja executado

Segue um exemplo pratico:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Um pouco mais afundo, você pode verificar o texto retornando e realizar uma validação usando expressão regular, retornando true ou false para a condição estabelecida por você.

Ficaria assim:

```
    $("#buscarID").click(function(e){
        var texto = $("#buscar").val();
        if(validaString(texto)){
            // chama algo
        }else{
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

 //Aqui ele só irá retornar true, caso o value for um texto de a-z ou numeros.
 function validaString(value){
     var filter = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/;
     if(filter.test(value)){return true;}
 }
```

Comment: Preservando as boas práticas, seria interessante colocar um return false na função validaString(), pois se não bater com a expressão não vai retornar nada, vai resultar num undefined. Mas a sua solução, creio que resolve o problema dele.